# emacs syntax highlight under ruby mode won't work with "<<" operator

Tags: ruby, emacs

The problem is that when I tried to use "<<" operator, ruby mode thinks this as an error and all codes below lost their syntax highlights, similar situation to lost brackets or quotes. Anyway to solve this?? Emacs 22 23 both applies.

As shown below:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a short example?

Comment: I took a look (in Emacs 23.2) and I couldn't see any problems with syntax highlight in `ruby-mode` following the `<<` operator. But maybe your code has some particular feature that provokes a bug? So you need to post your example. (But you might try upgrading first.)

Comment: I installed Cocoa emacs 23 and Aqua-emacs. All the same. I inspected the packaged ruby-mode.el and replace it with the latest version and re-byte-compile it into ruby-mode.elc. Nothings works. If still nobody can figure this out, I am going give up emacs and go back to textmate. I am serious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer myself, as explained below:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/95762

It is because the syntax ambiguity of Ruby language, which makes the current ruby-mode.el unable to distinguish which usage "<<" is hereby applied.

Close to the end of the above discussion, even **Maz** himself stood up to say:

```
|Steve, in that case Emacs ruby-mode is incorrect.

Maybe Ruby is too smart for this issue, since it's difficult for
editors to determine here-doc from shift operators without serious
parsing.

              matz.
```

Some other discussion of the quirky ruby-mode on syntax highlighting: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/119917

This takes me three hours, eerrrr... I guess I will stick to the textmate especially on ruby/RoR/Sinatra development until some serious ruby-mode emerges.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than abandon emacs (a whole new universe awaits you if you stick with it - it's more than an editor, more than and IDE), perhaps you could start inserting whitespace between your tokens? It's unfortunate that there seems to be a de facto ruby style for excluding whitespace after '<<' even for methods and singletons.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have been using emacs and inserted spaces before and after << operand. Now I quite enjoy it~~

Answer (score 0):

At first, I didn't manage to repeat the problem here. After a while I realized that I had an old version, dating from 2007, in my load path. (It colored one line wrong.) Maybe you could use it as an interim solution?

Please submit this as a bug to the Emacs team, as Emacs is capable of coloring more complex constructs than this. (Skip the part containing the hook setup, as it is irrelevant.)

Comment: Thanks dude. I will submit this. Hope to see some lexical parsing improvement to solve this...