# Commented string to fix emacs ruby mode highlighting

Tags: ruby, emacs, comments, syntax-highlighting

Sometimes, parsing done by text editors for syntax highlighting is not accurate. It often happens that introducing a heredoc in ruby-mode messes up syntax highlighting on emacs as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165132/emacs-syntax-highlight-under-ruby-mode-wont-work-with-operator). I am having problem with such case:

```
<<_
  some here doc content
  ...
  last line of the intended heredoc
_
this_ruby_code_line_and_any_line_after_it_is_highlightened_as_part_of_heredoc
```

I do not expect a fix on emacs ruby-mode for this, but is there some kind of a commented string that I can generally put between the heredoc and the following Ruby code in order to reset the highlighting problem? When I have problems not with heredoc but with funky string literals (especially those including quotes), sometimes, putting a commented string like

```
#"'`
```

at the end of the line fixes the problem. Is there such thing to fix the problem for heredoc, and further, is there a string that can be used more generally?

Comment: Though I can’t reproduce the bug with my emacs installation, I would suggest to use something “closing” for the symbols, causing a problem. In your case that might be smth like `#_>>`.

Comment: Sorry for my laziness. I love reading regexes in Ruby or PCRE, but I do not have enough energy to dig into ruby-mode.el and read regexes in emacs lisp.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me in an Emacs trunk build.

Try a more recent Emacs version (I'm quite certain that this works in the upcoming 24.3 version, but maybe in the current release, too) and/or make sure that you are using `ruby-mode` bundled with Emacs, not installed through ELPA, etc:

```lisp
ELISP> (require 'which-func)
which-func
ELISP> (find-library-name "ruby-mode")
"/home/gutov/emacs-bzr/trunk/lisp/progmodes/ruby-mode.el"
```

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded to emacs 24, and the problem is fixed.